# Adding Active Directory users using SPE and Show-ListView

Tags: powershell-extensions, sheer-ui

We have implemented SSO with Sitecore.  However, we don't want to allow all users to be able to log in to Sitecore, so the users are created in the extranet domain manually.

I'm trying to make the process of adding the Active Directory users to a Sitecore server.  Seems like SPE can go a long ways towards that.  I can use SPE to create dialogs (**Read-Variable**) to log on to the Active Directory, then query for users, and put the result into a **Show-ListView**.  All good so far.

Now, when I select a user, what do I need to feed **Show-ListView** with a custom action to create the user in Sitecore.  I'm sure I can do this, but can't find any good examples.  I can't see if I need to use the ActionData parameter, or the ViewName parameter.

Do I need to create a SHEER dialog, and use that as the view name?  Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the documentation on building reports? it should describe how to add custom report actions. You can also name them in such a way that the actions only appear for your reports. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/reports/authoring-reports

Comment: Very nice, Michael!  Thank you!  I would not have expected to look in there, but I am now headed in the right direction!  And thank you for such an amazing addition to Sitecore!